# Using comment tags above html tag

Tags: html, comments

Is there anything wrong with putting a comment tag above the `<html>` or `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag?

For example

```
<!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser-->
<html>
```

or

```
<!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

I'd like to create a bit of an intro to my webpage for anyone viewing my source code but don't want it to affect validation or ranking etc.

Thanks

Comment: This is of course totally valid and should also not influence ranking; __but__ it will send older IE into quirks mode.

Comment: And it might get problematic when it gets very long. Browsers only look into the first 512 bytes of a HTML file to see if they can find a `<meta charset>` command. If the comment pushes the `<meta>` beyond the 512 char limit, the browser may not identify the encoding correctly. (A solution to this would be to put the charset in the HTTP header, naturally.)